# normal vector and distribution of $||X||^2$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a normal vector $N_d(\mu,I_d).$ Let $\gamma= \ ^t\mu \mu.$

Prove that the distribution of $Y= \ ^tXX=||X||^2$ depends of $d$ and $\gamma.$

Since $X $ is $N_d(\mu,I_d)$ all the components $X_k$ are normal $N(\mu_k,1)$ and independent.

So $P_{Y}(B)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{d/2}}\int_{R^d}1_B(\sum_{k=1}^dx_k^2)e^{-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^d(x_k-\mu_k)^2}dx_1...dx_d$

How can we prove that the above quantity depends only of $d,\gamma?$

Comment: A sum of squared normals is a chi-squared random variable: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_distribution

Comment: This has a [non-central chi-square distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution) with noncentrality parameter $\mu^t\mu$ and degrees of freedom $d$.

Comment: But why this distribution depends, only, of $\gamma,d?$ (for example not of $\sum_k\mu_k$)